# Access Denied when creating a scheduled task with powershell and the com schedule.service object

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-task

I have a powershell script that creates a scheduled task using a call to RegisterTask via the Schedule.Service com object.

Essentially:

```
$ts = new-object -com Schedule.Service
$ts.Connect()
$rootfolder = $ts.GetFolder("\")
$taskXml = Get-Content "Task.xml"
$rootfolder.RegisterTask("\Maintenance", $taskXml, 6, "LOCAL SERVICE", $null, 5)
```

This works fine on my local machine (windows 7, and I am a local admin)

When I try this on the machine it will be run on, the RegisterTask call fails with ACCESS_DENIED.

However, if I run a command prompt as administrator, then `powershell.exe -file myscript.sps1` it works fine and adds the task.

I have ensured that the user that it is running under has permissions to write to the Tasks folders in %windir% and %windir%/system32

The user is in the Administrators group, which is puzzling, what else do I need to do to give the user the permissions to create scheduled tasks? It seems that just adding them to the local administrators group isn't enough.

EDIT: I have logged onto the server as the user that will be running the script. I can successfully import the xml file into the Task Scheduler UI addin manually.

Comment: Did you already create the Maintenance folder?

Comment: No, I didn't need to when running it locally. I also changed the script to create the task in the root folder and get the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Since Powershell 4.0 you can use the `ScheduledTask` module to create Scheduled tasks without the use of the com-object and easier reading and writing.

Example:

```
$Action    = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "Taskmgr.exe"
$Trigger   = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogon
$Principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal "Laptop\Administrator"
$Settings  = New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet

$Task = New-ScheduledTask `
    -Action $Action `
    -Principal $Principal `
    -Trigger $Trigger `
    -Settings $Settings

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName Task1 -InputObject $Task
```

The first command uses the `New-ScheduledTaskAction` cmdlet to assign the variable `$Action` to the executable file `tskmgr.exe`.

The second command uses the `New-ScheduledTaskTrigger` cmdlet to assign the variable `$Trigger` to the value `AtLogon`.

The third command assigns the variable `$Principal` to the principal of the scheduled task, `Contoso\Administrator`.

The fourth command uses the `New-ScheduledTaskSettingsSet` cmdlet to assign the variable `$Settings` to a task settings object.

The fifth command creates a new task and assigns the variable `$Task` to the task definition.

The sixth command (hypothetically) runs at a later time. It registers the new scheduled task and defines it by using the `$Task` variable.

Dont forget the run the code as `Administrator`. [Source.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtask?view=win10-ps)

Answer (score 0):

I gave up in the end, couldn't find a way to do this using register tasks, however using `schtasks` allowed me to import the xml file of the task without the access denied error. I could also use schtasks to import the task to a remote machine.